# Using IIS URL Rewite to get rid of a subfolder name in my URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

My current URL looks like: http://www.example.com/files/maps.html

I want it to look like: http://www.example.com/maps.html

Basically, I just want to get rid of the "/files/" portion of the URL. I am using IIS URL Rewrite module, but am unfamiliar with it and am unfamiliar with reg expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />

            <rule name="Removefoldername" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^abc$|^abc/page1.html$" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="page1.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteToFile">
                <match url="^(?!abc/)page1.html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="abc/page1.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>

    </rewrite>
```

Comment: tried it, but seems to interfere with my other rules. What I have: `
         <rule name="Hide .html ext">
             <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
             <conditions>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
   </rule>`

Comment: continued: `<rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^(.*).html"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                 <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
    </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
         </rule>`

Comment: @CancerPatient555 in my opinion, it is impossible to use both rules together. it will conflict with each other. other.if you just want to remove the folder name then you could place this rule at the fist position `<rule name="Removefoldername" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^abc$|^abc/page1$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="page1.html" />
                </rule>`